# vuejs: sticky footer in mobile AND display view

Tags: html, css, vue.js, footer

How to create a sticky footer on desktop AND also mobile view? The following code overlaps the main content. When setting in footer `position: relative;` it doesn't overlap, but also doesn't stick to bottom. I need a responsive solution.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavbarComponent/>
    <router-view/>
    <FooterComponent/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavbarComponent from "./components/Navbar" 
import FooterComponent from "./components/FooterComponent"

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  }
}

</script>
<style>

    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
    }

</style>
```

FooterComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <footer>
    <p class="text-center">Some random text for the footer.</p>
  </footer>
</template>

<script></script>

<style scoped>
  footer {
    color: white;
    background-color: #003459;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of ways to turn a footer sticky in bottom. You can try using a flex.

```
<body>
 <div class='container'></div>
 <div class='footer'></div>
</body>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  flex: 1; //or 1 0 auto
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
</style>
```

Very clean and fast. 
Or you can try with reduced height...

```
.container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
.footer {
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This sticks to the bottom of the content, but not to the bottom of the viewport / display. Means if the content is one line of text, then the footer is almost at the top of the page.